# Add class name to product attribute

Tags: product, product-attribute, custom-options, css, custom

I am trying to add a class name to a product attribute on my site so that I can change the colour of one of the attributes to green. I am able to to do this by simply using the class name "Last" which is fine at the moment.

However I have also customised the attributes so that that when the product attribute is empty it does not display on the frontend. This means that my styling using the class name "last" to add the green text is no longer working correctly because it means if my attribute is empty this green styling is added to the next attribute in the list which is not what I want.

Any advise is appreciated.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you supply with a link? :)

Comment: have you created product attribute? If created then use which page ? can you explain in details??

Comment: Yes here is a link http://www.therosegallery.co.uk/artists/debbie-boon/debbie-boon-a-moments-pause I am trying to make the text "Online Exclusive" green, I cannot use the class name "last" because sometimes this attribute is not always on the page so this would make "Mounted Size" green instead.

Comment: I, too, would like an answer to this question!